# Google Calendar Feeds Don't Show Individual Date for Recurring Events?

Tags: calendar, rss, google-calendar-api, recurring

I am using Google Calendars in my app, and I parse the feed.  However, I am noticing that on recurring events, it never seems to put in individual dates anywhere.  In the feed, all I see is the date that it first started, but never any specific dates.  Is there a way around this?  Basically, an event is set up for every Sunday morning, but I need the specific dates for that, and the feed doesn't contain any of it.

The feed in question is:

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mehyouth%40gmail.com/public/basic?futureevents=true

Answer (score 0):

GData API generating the feeds is [deprecated](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ch/2014/06/calendar-gdata-api-google-calendar.html), please switch to [API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). In v3, when you want to get the individual instances of a recurring event, you can use the Events.instances() call or set singleEvents=true on the Events.list() call.